# Kafka - Retries and Recovery not invoked

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have implemented a custom listener i.e. not using the @KafkaListener annotation due to the fact that my application need to dynamically lsiten to topics. I have seen suggestions of moving to Spring kafka 2.6.x but I can't upgrade due to the fact that I am stuck (at least for now) with Spring 5.1.X.RELEASE which means I can only use Spring-kafka 2.2.x.

My question is, how can I achieve retry, recovery and error handling with Spring-kafka 2.2.x?

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory listenerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
listenerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
configurer.configure(listenerFactory, consumerFactory);
listenerFactory.setConcurrency(listenerConcurrency); 
listenerFactory.setStatefulRetry(Boolean.TRUE);
listenerFactory.setBatchListener(isBatchListener);
listenerFactory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(chainedKafkaTransactionManager);
listenerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
listenerFactory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate(kafkaEhCacheRetryManager)); 
listenerFactory.setRecoveryCallback(kafkaRecoverer);
```

My retry template looks like:

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate(EhCacheCacheManager kafkaEhCacheRetryManager) {

ExponentialBackOffPolicy exponentialBackOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
exponentialBackOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(initialIntervalForRetries);
exponentialBackOffPolicy.setSleeper(new ThreadWaitSleeper());
exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2.0);
exponentialBackOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(maxIntervalForRetries);

RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
retryTemplate.setRetryContextCache(new KafkaEhRetryContextCache(kafkaEhCacheRetryManager));
retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(exponentialBackOffPolicy);

// KafkaTransactionalRetryPolicy extends SimpleRetryPolicy
KafkaTransactionalRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new KafkaTransactionalRetryPolicy(kafkaTemplate);
retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts);
retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(kafkaTransactionalRetryPolicy);

return retryTemplate;

}
```

My listener looks like:

```
public class MyKafkaListener implements MessageListener<String, String> {


    @Override
    @Transactional(value = "chainedKafkaTransactionManager")
    public void onMessage(final ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord){
       throw new RuntimeException("thrown out of out anger");
    }

}
```

with this config:

```
spring.kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: ${service.kakfa.host}
  admin:
    client-id: test-consumers
    bootstrap-servers: ${service.kakfa.host}
  consumer:
    bootstrap-servers: ${service.kakfa.host}
    group-id: local-consumers
    client-id: local-consumers
    auto-offset-reset: earliest
    value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    enable-auto-commit: false
    isolation-level: read_committed
  producer:
    bootstrap-servers: ${service.kakfa.host}
    client-id: local-producer
    acks: all
    retries: 3
    transaction-id-prefix: local-producer-tx-
    properties:
      enable.idempotence: true
      transactional.id: tran-id-1-
      max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 5
  listener.concurrency: 1
```

I have seen several examples on StackOverflow on how to do this, but none has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retry mechanism you are trying to use only applies to `@KafakListener`s. It is built into a listener adapter used to call the listener POJO.

In newer versions, the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` have a back off (Since 2.3), eliminating the need for a retry template at the listener level, in favor of retry at the container level.

With your own listener you would have to use a `RetryTemplate` within the listener code itself.

BTW, Spring 5.1.x is no longer supported https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#supported-versions

Comment: Pls can you point me in the direction of the @KafakListeners implementation so I can see a sample implementation (soruce code) or if you can direct me to a sample listener with its own retry implementation with RetryTemplate? And yes, I am aware the support has ended for Spring 5.1.x and will eventually move away from it, but not at this time.

Comment: The container factory (endpoint) wraps the listener adapter in a `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter`; the actual retry code is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/1a2f671c9c06587550ba5d25cd961506cf60413a/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/adapter/RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java#L114-L135). The wrapping is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/1a2f671c9c06587550ba5d25cd961506cf60413a/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java#L495-L498). You can use the same adapter.

Comment: One last question though, will I have to handle the error  (using ErrorHandler) in the listener or will it be handled at container level?

Comment: Since you are doing retries at the listener level, you could either add a `RecoveryCallback` to the listener adapter and handle the situation there (after the retries are exhausted), or you can add an error handler. I think with that old version, the default error handler simply logs the error.

Comment: So I added an handler and removed RecoveryCallback:

```
DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template);
SeekToCurrentErrorHandler stceh = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(recoverer, maxAttempts);
stceh.setCommitRecovered(true);
listenerFactory.setErrorHandler(stceh);
```

I have the failed message written to my DLQ topic 10 times. I thought the ErrorHandler is only called after the retrytemplate is exhausted *Retrytemplate has 3 max retry). It looks like it has its own retry and it writes to DLQ topic for each retry.

Comment: Don't add code in comments; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. When using both listener level retry and a STCEH, the retries are multiplied. The default STCEH retries 9 times (10 delivery attempts) so with 3 retries at the listener level, I would expect 30 delivery attempts, but only one publish to the DLT so something is amiss with your configuration. You should set the STCEH max attempts to not retry at all. The best solution is to upgrade to a supported version and eliminate the retry template.